# Plotting composition of two functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

I can't understand what is wrong with my code here in matlab:

```
syms t
x=[1 2 3];
g=t*t;
f=sin(x);
y=compose(g,f);
plot(x,y,'o')
```

this code I wrote to plot y=sin(x)^2 .As I don't have matlab in my computer so was running it on Octave online compiler , it is giving error `'syms' undefined near line 1 column 1`.

Please if anyone can help explaining where am I wrong in the code?

Comment: Simple check: Do you have the Symbolic Math Toolbox?

Comment: @Benoit_11 how to check it..

Comment: type 'ver' in the command window and you will see what Toolboxes are installed on your computer

Comment: there is no symbolic package for Octave anymore, so you don't have it. (well, technically there is but is old, deprecated, does not work well, and not easy to download from Octave Forge)

Comment: What's some easy source to download matlab ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the symbolic math toolbox installed so you can't use `compose`.  There is a way around it though.  Remember, the composition of two functions when calling `compose(f,g)` is such that we return `f(g(y))` for `f = f(x)` and `g = g(y)`.

What you can do is plot this numerically, without relying on `syms`.  Declare a numeric time vector that is... say... from `t = 0` to `t = 5` in steps of `0.01`.  After, declare your own function handles that will compute each function.  Function handles or anonymous functions are small one-liner functions that usually are mathematical or computational statements that can take an input of any size, whether it be a single value, a vector or a matrix and applies that computational statement to every value in your input.  You signify the anonymous function by the `@` symbol, then within round brackets, you specify the variables that will compose of the statement you want to compute.  In this case, there is just a single variable which we will call `t`, but it can be any variable really.

Therefore, I define a function `g` that performs `t^2` to every element in our input.  Note that I have to do element-by-element operations.  If we just did `t*t`, should I provide a vector or a matrix, this will be interpreted as matrix multiplication and this is not what you want.  Similarly, we define an anonymous function `f` such that it produces `sin(t)` as the output.

With these defined, all you really need to do is:

```
t = 0 : 0.01 : 5;
g = @(t) t.*t;
f = @(t) sin(t);
y = g(f(t)); %// Composition of the two functions (compose(g,f));
plot(t, y, 'o');
```

Comment: thanks your method worked .but can you just explain me what does  @(t) means in  g = @(t) t.*t;

Comment: @coool - Sure.  Let me add to my post, but you are essentially creating an anonymous function `g` where you put in values and it computes `t^2`.  As such, put any time values you want in the function... it can be a single value, a matrix or a vector, and it applies `t^2` to every element in this matrix.